# How do i build Xamarin.Forms UWP AM64 App?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, arm64

How do i build Xamarin Forms UWP app for ARM64.. is see the ARM but not ARM64.  and the xappupload file does not build for ARM64

I have looked around and all i can find are some problems/bug fixes on ARM64, but not how to build it for ARM64, so i'm just lost on what to do.  I want my app that is already on store, to be available for my Surface Pro X as well.

Comment: Does the following answer your question, if the answer is helpful please consider mark it.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i build Xamarin.Forms UWP AM64 App?

Please check [Windows 10 on ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/apps-on-arm#universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps) official document

> Now, Windows 10 desktop can run on machines that are powered by ARM64 processors with the Fall Creators Update or newer. The power-saving nature of the ARM CPU architecture allows these PCs to have all-day battery life and support for mobile data networks.

To build your UWP application to natively target the ARM64 platform, you must have Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 or later, or Visual Studio 2019. For more information, see this [blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/11/15/official-support-for-windows-10-on-arm-development/).

We suggest you build your app with Visual studio 2019 latest version that could deploy ARM64 directly.